# Вывести wchar_t в ncurses с помощью printw

Tags: c++, curses

```
std::vector<wchar_t> str(1024);
int size = libfptr_get_param_str(fptr, LIBFPTR_PARAM_SERIAL_NUMBER, 
&str[0], str.size());
if (size > str.size())
{
    str.resize(size);
libfptr_get_param_str(fptr, LIBFPTR_PARAM_SERIAL_NUMBER, &str[0], 
str.size());
}
std::wstring serialNumber = std::wstring(&str[0]);
```

Вывести в терминал могу так `std::wcout << serialNumber << std:: endl;`
Но мне нужно вывести в ncurses меню там используется printw.
На что получаю ошибку `main.cpp:168:25: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::wstring {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int printw(const char*, ...)’
     printw (serialNumber);`
Компилятор g++
Вопрос в том, как вывести в ncurses?

Comment: Преобразуйте строку в многобайтовую кодировку чтобы получился `char const *`.

Comment: Сделал, error:cannot convert.

Comment: Что сделал? Все телепаты в отпуске... А лучше задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо как это сделать?  Я преобразовывал много раз, разными способами.

Comment: @Dr.robot, скорей всего не правильно сделал — в плюсах полноценная конвертация многобайтовой строки в обычную сделана через жопу (а именно через сишную `wctomb()`)...

Comment: по проблеме — дай полноценный [mcve]. тут или использовать широкосимвольную версию — `ncursesw`, или `%ls`. в printf формате.

Comment: Для запуска кода нужно будет подключать заголовочный файл и библиотеку. Я думаю будет не очень удобно. И кода много. Если у вас есть возможность взять пример из гугла, самый простой пример ncurses, создать в нем массив wchar_t как на примере и вывести его на экран. Думаю будет тоже самое.

Comment: Сам допер, нужно сначала конвертировать wstring в string а потом в char. Всем спасибо.